# Align labels of axis with type category under ticks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart that looks like the following example (copied from Highcharts samples and modified for my question's use):

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/zryrgh3f/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Chart reflow is set to true'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'When resizing the window or the frame, the chart should resize'
    },


    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
        labels: {
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

What I really need, for the same data set, is this:

[image]

The labels should shift leftwards to beneath the ticks, and an additional label for the next number (the labels' values are computed so the value to be added is known beforehand) should be added underneath the last tick (written in red above). Note that the data points' positions relative to the ticks do **not** change.

I'm guessing I'll need to artificially add the additional tick, but how do I do that, and how do I correctly position all of my labels in the first place? In my second chart I hard-coded the number of pixels to offset but I'm looking for a better, more dynamic solution since my actual chart's size can vary as it resizes.

Comment: I think that you should be able to use xAxis.tickmarkPlacement for changing position of your labels: http://jsfiddle.net/zryrgh3f/1/

Comment: It changes the position of the labels but also the position of the data points, which are now on the ticks too. I don't want the data point positions relative to the ticks to change, only the labels.

Comment: In this case you should be able to use pointPlacement option: http://jsfiddle.net/zryrgh3f/3/

Comment: That does it. Feel free to post it as a formal answer for me to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of your chart you should be able to use xAxis.tickmarkPlacement with pointPlacement option of your series. This options allow you to have labels on ticks and dataPoints between ticks.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointPlacement

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Chart reflow is set to true'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'When resizing the window or the frame, the chart should resize'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13'],
    min: 0,
    max: 12,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    labels: {}
  },
  series: [{
  pointPlacement: 'between',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zryrgh3f/3/

Comment: Is pointPlacement necessary? When I was experimenting around earlier it seems being categories place them in the middle by default.

Comment: With tickmarkPlacement your series points are moved on ticks - that is the reason why I used pointPlacement.